# Regex expression to split SQL create statements

Tags: python, regex

I have a schema file with all the create statements of my database and I'd like to split them to get each individual statement:

```sql
CREATE TABLE leads (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name text NOT NULL,
    email text NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE lead_logs (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    old_id int,
    new_id int,
    old_email text,
    new_email text
);
CREATE TRIGGER validate_email_before_insert_leads 
   BEFORE INSERT ON leads
BEGIN
   SELECT
      CASE
    WHEN NEW.email NOT LIKE '%_@__%.__%' THEN
      RAISE (ABORT,'Invalid email address')
       END;
END;
CREATE TRIGGER log_contact_after_update 
   AFTER UPDATE ON leads
   WHEN old.phone <> new.phone
        OR old.email <> new.email
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO lead_logs VALUES(
        old.id,
        new.id,
        old.email,
        new.email
    );
END;
```

I could work by splitting the text on <kbd>;</kbd>  when all I had were `CREATE TABLE` statements, but now that I also have `CREATE TRIGGER` with `BEGIN` and `END` commands, which also get a semicolon, I'd need a more intelligent way to extract the full statements.

Since each statement begins with `CREATE` and ends with `;\n` before the following `CREATE`, I though I could compile `(CREATE.*;)\nCREATE` using the `DOTALL` flag so the newlines are considered by the dot, but  python's `re.findall` only returns a **single extraction containing everything but the last statement**.

I though it could be something relating to the subgroup, but `((CREATE.*;)\n)*` returns only **empty strings** and `CREATE.*;\n` will return **the whole original text**.

I could use python to simply prepend the `CREATE` sequences with something else and split, but that seems rather primitive:

```py
txt.replace('CREATE', 'OOGABOOGA-CREATE').split('OOGABOOGA-')
```

I'm sure this is simple as hell in regex, but I can't wrap my head around it, can someone lend me a hand?

Comment: Use _split()_ to split the records on the starting text.

Comment: split on word `CREATE` - `split("CREATE")` - and later add word `CREATE` to results. Maybe it is promitive but it works and probably for long strings it can work faster then `regex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist to use regexp, use **non-greedy regex** with syntax `?` to avoid getting the whole original text. And look for lines that end with `;` without leading spaces. It only works when your data is formatted like your example.

```py
print([s[0] for s in re.findall('(CREATE[\s\S]+?(\n[^ ]+;))', sql)])
```

**Output**:

```
['CREATE TABLE leads (\n    id integer PRIMARY KEY,\n    first_name text NOT NULL,\n    email text NOT NULL\n);',
 'CREATE TABLE lead_logs (\n    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,\n    old_id int,\n    new_id int,\n    old_email text,\n    new_email text\n);',
 "CREATE TRIGGER validate_email_before_insert_leads \n   BEFORE INSERT ON leads\nBEGIN\n   SELECT\n      CASE\n    WHEN NEW.email NOT LIKE '%_@__%.__%' THEN\n      RAISE (ABORT,'Invalid email address')\n       END;\nEND;",
 'CREATE TRIGGER log_contact_after_update \n   AFTER UPDATE ON leads\n   WHEN old.phone <> new.phone\n        OR old.email <> new.email\nBEGIN\n    INSERT INTO lead_logs VALUES(\n        old.id,\n        new.id,\n        old.email,\n        new.email\n    );\nEND;']
```